# How do I get all IPs that a single Amazon Route 53 A Record entry is pointing to?

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-route53, a-record

I am using Amazon's Route 53 to set up zones for a domain. I have multiple A Records set up as an Alias to a bunch of targets. These aliases have a Weighted routing policy.

They look something as follows:

```
A     foo.mydomain.com     ALIAS srv1.mydomain.com
A     foo.mydomain.com     ALIAS srv2.mydomain.com
A     foo.mydomain.com     ALIAS srv3.mydomain.com
```

I am looking for a Unix call I can make with `foo.mydomain.com` as the parameters and returns me a list of all the three hostnames above as the result.

Is this possible through (without using the Amazon SDK)?

Thank you

Comment: Your question title says IP addresses, but your question itself says "returns me a list of all the three hostnames."  What do you want? Hostnames or IP addresses?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot sorry, hostname. Either way, if I have any of them I can translate them into another

Answer (score 2):

In short, the answer is no.  You've configured it in a way that it's not possible through a DNS query to get all the possible records in one request.

Either `dig` or `nslookup` should return the IP adresses... however, it's not likely to return more than  one at a time if you are using a weighted policy -- that is the point, to return them at certain frequencies -- some more than others if they weights are different.

There is not a way to query for the hostnames, of course, because these are aliases.  That's the point of an alias, *not*  to return the target, but rather the record that would have been returned had the target been directly requested.

The aws-cli's `aws route53 list-resource-record-sets` should be able to be used to query this, but that's not a "Unix" command that's installed on a system by default.